# Submit canvas image as attachment (without ajax submission)

Tags: php, ajax, html5-canvas

I want to retrieve the attached file by using `$_FILES['name']`. But, if I use ajax, it always send data in `POST` variable with `base64` encoding.

is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the direct method to save your canvas as an image on the server:

- Ajax post (submit the canvas as base64 data)
- base64_decode (decode the base64 data)
- file_put_contents (save the decoded data as an image file on the server)

An alternate Indirect method:

- Open a new browser tab with an image created from the canvas using toDataURL
- Have the user right-click-save-as the image to their desktop
- Use a form and input-type=file to upload the desktop image to the server.

In the indirect method, you might be able to use a 3rd party script to save your canvas to the user's desktop (CORS security restrictions apply).  One example of this kind of script is FileSaverJs:  https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/